# How to make celery consumes queue separately on each machines from one rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I found the solution. Its so easy to use:)

Set "-n mynode@%h" when start celery
and set the destination option like add_consumer 
(queue=myqueue, destination=['mynode@hostname']).

Thanks.

=========================================

I use flask, celery, rabbitmq.

I want to divide server A and B by purpose of messages with same rabbitmq.

```
0. workers are always running on two servers(A, B) with this options.
    celery -A myapp.mycelery worker -E --logfile=celery.log --pidfile=celery.pid

1. Make queue dynamically with CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES=True option.

2. add consumer to run of newly maked queue.
    mycelery.control.add_consumer(new_queue_name, reply=False)

3. Server A, B have 8 workers each. (total 16 workers)

4. add messages.
    my_task.apply_async((params), queue=new_queue_name)

5. 16 workers process my_task messages concurrently very well.
```

But I want to divide server A and B by purpose of messages with same rabbitmq.

```
For example 1)
    my_task_A.apply_async() -> run on server A only.
    my_task_B.apply_async() -> run on server B only.

For example 2)
    my_task.apply_async(queue=new_queue_name_startswith_A) -> run on server A only.
    my_task.apply_async(queue=new_queue_name_startswith_B) -> run on server B only.
```

The queue what I make dynamically is direct exchange.
(One message must be in one queue)
And I can't increase number of rabbitmq servers.

Please let me know good way to do. or what term I need to study?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you want to separate different message types to different machines? ('my_task_A' to machine A and 'my_task_B' to machine B)? If so, why don't you use two different workers that consume messages from a different queues?

Comment: ItalyB, that's write what I want to do as you say. But when I try to 'add_consumer' on server A from python script, all messages are consumed by not only server A but also server B. Of course I make new queue always by purpose! I try to set '--queues' or '--exclude-queues' options when start celery workers on server A and B, but it's affected neither.

Comment: Did u follow celery tutorial? U don't need to use add consume no where..

Comment: Of course I followed tutorial but I couldn't find why the options are not affected. So I'll use destination option on add_consumer instead of --queues option. Thanks :)

Comment: You can  answer to your own question below, it might help someone some day.. :-) thanks for updating